# Selecting items ending exactly with some suffixes

Tags: xslt

I have this XML:

```
<items>
    <item name="a_1"/>
    <item name="a_2"/>
    <item name="b_1"/>
    <item name="b_2"/>
    <item name="b_3"/>
    <item name="c_1"/>
    <item name="c_2"/>
    <item name="d_1"/>
</items>
```

I would like to select items that end exactly with `_1` or `_2`. For example, `a_1` and `a_2` are ok, but `b_1` and `b_2` are not, because `b_3` exists. `d_1` is not ok because `d_2` doesn't exists. So the output would be:

```
<items>
    <item name="a_1"/>
    <item name="a_2"/>
    <item name="c_1"/>
    <item name="c_2"/>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you could group first and then check with `every .. satisfies`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="wanted-suffixes" select="'1', '2'"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="substring-before(@name, '_')">
      <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) eq count($wanted-suffixes)
                    and (every $item in current-group() satisfies 
                        (some $suffix in $wanted-suffixes satisfies ends-with($item/@name, $suffix)))">
         <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not correct because `d_1` is incorrect. It wouldn't be a problem if I could save the results of this loop into a variable, because then I could exclude them. Also `group_by` -> `group-by`

Comment: Your textual description in your question says "I would like to select items that end with _1 or _2 only". So why is `d_1` not correct? I will edit to correct the `group_by` to `group-by`, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, but as you can see the output that I want to get doesn't include `d_1`. I'll improve the description.

Comment: I will edit the code, check whether the new version does what you want.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. I think that the only uncovered case is when there are items not uniques. Do you think that is possible to store the results into a variable?

Comment: You can store stuff in a variable simply by wrapping the code into a variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="varname" as="element(item)"><xsl:for-each-group ...>...</xsl:for-each-group></xsl:variable>`. Whether you need that I can't tell, if there are further requirements and you can't implement them yourself you might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ends-with function.

http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_ends-with.html

Comment: How could I use it for this case?